# 「～を限りに」 vs「～限りで」

Tags: grammar

> ①　三年前、「俺は今日を限りにタバコをやめるんだ！」といったアイツは昨日煙草による肺癌で死んじまった。

The sentence above was corrected by numerous Japanese people as in the following sentence.

> ①　三年前、「俺は今日限りでタバコをやめるんだ！」といったアイツは昨日煙草による肺癌で死んじまった。

What's the difference between these two expressions? When should one be used over the other? (I asked this question as well, but I was told that it's hard even for Japanese people.)

Comment: 今日を限りに and 今日限りで means exactly the same, 今日を限りに might feel a little more stiff but that's it.

Comment: Yeah, my grammar book written by Japanese also said it's interchangeable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel both are fine. To me, 今日を限りに sounds a little more pompous and stilted. But in this case it's not a bad word choice because it expresses the guy's resolution well.

Answer (score 0):

"今日を限りに" is little formal sentence, I feel.

Comment: To help the facilitate the learning of the person that asked the question, would you mind expounding on your answer?  Why do you feel it is a little formal?

Comment: When we pronounce "今日を限りに", we don't focus "を".